# dd copied UUID - How to make GRUB2 find the correct partition?

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dd

Using Grub2 on Ubuntu LTS Xenial

On sda1, I dd the partition to sdb1(which already has GRUB2 on the MBR) with `sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=1M`.

I found that it also copied the UUID. So, both /dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 have the same UUID as verified with blkid.

```
root@localhost:/home/one# blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b7bb1151-01"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b7bb1151-01"
```

Since grub uses UUID this is causing a issue. If I boot off of sdb1, I get to the grub menu. But when I pick the menu entry it just freezes.

/boot/grub/grub.cfg

```
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd1,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd1,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd1,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci1,msdos1  e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-46-generic root=UUID=e5d43e2f-05d1-4c08-b981-b27d2144373e ro libata.force=noncq splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-46-generic
}
```

Comment: change it with `tune2fs -U`?

Comment: It should be impossible for `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` to have the same `UUID`. That said use a different method of cloning other than `dd` or **Clonezilla**: https://askubuntu.com/a/1064000/307523

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Did you really mean impossible?  Copying the UUID is expected behaviour for `dd`.

Comment: Just use `/dev/sdb1` instead of the UUID to test before you use `tune2fs -U` or remove `/dev/sda` from the system.